# Rails controller needs to accept cross-domain post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cross-domain, bookmarklet

I'm new to Rails and indeed to web development.  I'm trying to do a cross-domain post (I think) and have no clue how to do it.

I have a rails app running on webrick, let's call this 'myapp'.

I have written a bookmarklet which when selected should grab the URL from whatever website the user is on and post it to 'myapp' to be saved for that user (who will need to give his email address).  How would I write a controller to deal with this?

Comment: Is your problem the browser is not posting across the domain? Or that your controller is ignoring the parameters you're receiving?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be specific with the amount of info you've provided, but general, you'll need to set up a route to handle the request, and define a controller action to do what you want with it.
Assuming the requests look something like `POST http://myapp.com/bookmarks/create` with parameters for the user's email and the url they're on, that means doing something like this:

in routes.rb:

```
resources :bookmarks
```

in bookmarks_controller.rb:

```
def create
  if params[:email]
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if @user
      @user.bookmarks.create!(:url => params[:url]
    end
  end
end
```